# Difficulty combining WebForms and Razor in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

1. We've got a bunch of views that I've moved to Razor because I hate WebForms and we don't have an excessive amount of views to change, but there's still some that I haven't yet gotten to that are in Webforms. We also have some partial views in .ascx and I haven't moved any of those to Razor yet, but they are referenced from both WebForms and Razor views.
2. We also have mobile versions of most of our views . If I've changed the non mobile version of a view to Razor, I've also changed the mobile version. We have a button on the site that lets you manually choose to switch to the mobile view or standard view, by it setting a cookie.

When there were no Razor views, the view engines just looked like this

```
ViewEngines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine("Mobile", Controllers.SafetyLineController.MobileViewFormatChooser) { NotSupportedViewName = "HttpExceptionNotImplemented.Mobile" });
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
```

I then changed it to the following

```
ViewEngines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileCapableRazorViewEngine("Mobile", Controllers.SafetyLineController.MobileViewFormatChooser));
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine("Mobile", Controllers.SafetyLineController.MobileViewFormatChooser) { NotSupportedViewName = "HttpExceptionNotImplemented.Mobile" });
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
```

This worked fine for the normal views, but the mobile views over the whole site were totally broken. Hitting any of the mobile pages just gives a blank white screen in the browser whether you get there via an actual mobile device, or by using the button. Debugging hasn't been particularly useful as this only happens once the site is deployed to our IIS server on the dev machine. Local testing works completely fine (we use the built in ASP.NET web server locally).

It seems like it's some issue with the view engine set up, but I haven't been able to figure out what that is from my googling research.

The error that I get when the white screen happens is

```
Exception Thrown:
Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The view at '~/Views/User/History.Mobile.aspx' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
Source: System.Web.Mvc
```

So I guess generally speaking the issue happens when any .aspx or .ascx mobile view is loaded.